# Mongo db updateOne query hanging

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a c# application reading and writing to a MongoDB database using the latest drivers (2.3.0). It is processing a large number of messages from an event queue.

The MongoClient and IMongoCollection are bound in singleton scope in my IoC container for the application (which is single threaded) as per the recommendation here http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/reference/driver/connecting/

Most of the time everything works perfectly.

Very occasionally (one in every few hundred thousand messages) the driver completely locks up while calling `collection.UpdateOne`. It appears to simply never return from this method, with no CPU or memory usage.

The query causing the lock appears pretty unremarkable (eg of the same format as all of the other messages). The only thing I have noticed is that in both cases I have observed it the query is fairly large as its setting an array with several thousand elements in it.

```
{
    "$addToSet": {
        "Events": {
            "Timestamp": ISODate("2007-06-10T21:33:45Z"),
            "CorrelationKey": CSUUID("a0dacaf9-2ea9-4bbd-bb26-abdc99961438"),
            "GroupIds": [ ]
        }
    },
    "$set": {
        "Spans": [
            {
                "GroupId": 1166,
                "From": ISODate("2007-06-10T21:31:43Z"),
                "To": ISODate("2007-06-10T21:33:45Z")
            },
            ....
            {
                "GroupId": 33549,
                "From": ISODate("2007-06-10T21:31:43Z"),
                "To": ISODate("2007-06-10T21:33:45Z")
            }
        ]
    },
    "$inc": { "Version": 1 }
}
```

**Is there some error condition I need to handle around the driver that is putting me into this state?**

**What else could I do to find what is causing this?**

Comment: I'd suggest to enable profiling to get clear picture of issue.

Comment: @Saleem I ran the profiler, the command which failed from C# was not shown in the profiler list

Comment: Hmm. Just food for thoughts. You mentioned that it hangs when you set an array with several thousands elements. If this is the case, isn't it's time to split your document into two? See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/

Comment: @Saleem I could possibly split the array into chunks inside the same document, (I wouldn't want to split into separate ones as I need it to do an atomic write). having said that I do really want to find out why its hanging as thats probably a symptom of another issue which needs fixing.

Comment: We're running into this issue as well. Updating a small document hangs forever in one out of several thousand calls. The memory dump says that the thread is stuck in 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive' inside 'MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytes'. Even Thread.Abort() does not seem to yank it out of the hang.